# Error Design not member of System.Window.Form

Tags: vb.net

Design not memberof System.Window.Form.I has been use (import System.Drawing)

[image]

Comment: You'll need to add a reference to the System.Drawing library. This is covered in any introductory .NET programming book.

Comment: I try this already but not work .. but thx

Answer (score 0):

I've got some error before similar to that. the cause of the problem is that you deleted or modified some of the properties of that form accidentally. try to make another form then copy all the component from it if there are some and delete the previous one.. it might fixed the error..